# Node + Q with expressjs - ordered promisses

Tags: node.js, express, q

I want to execute a set of functions in the order they were written and in the end to release the request to the client.

for example see the mock code bellow:

```
router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res, next) {

    var json = {items : 0}
    Q.fcall(
      function(){
         //first exec
         json.items+=1;
      }
    ).then(
      function(){
         //scond exec
         json.items+=1;
      }
    ).then(
      function(){
         //third exec
         json.items+=1;
      }
    ).finally(
      function(){
        //do this when all the other promises are don
        res.json(json);
     });

}
```

the finally function shoud be executed when all is done.

Can it be done with Q?

**UPDATE**
I think I mislead you, and did not give all the information, because i did not think its relevant, but it is...
I actually bringing data via mongoose, and mongoose is async asd well.
So it goes like this:

```
 Q.fcall(
        function() {
            Visitor.count(dateRange, function(err, data) {
                json.newVisitors = data;
            });
        }).then(
        function() {
            Account.count(dateRange, function(err, data) {
                json.newAccounts = data;
            });
        }).finally(
        function() {
            res.json(json);
        })
```

Comment: Didn't your code work?

Comment: its pseudo code, im looking for equivalent way to do it

Comment: Did you try it as this pseudo code? Looks like it should work.

Comment: Your code works as it is. You should the built-in Promise though, just replace `Q.fcall` by `Promise.resolve().then` and `finally` by `then`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoose is already promisified. Calling `exec()` on a query gives you a promise. Here are two ways of doing it:

Classic promises chaining:

```
Visitor.count(dateRange).exec().then(function (data) {
    json.newVisitors = data;
    return Account.count(dateRange).exec(); // return promise for chaining
}).then(function (data) {
    json.newAccounts = data;
}).then(function () {
    res.json(json);
}).catch(function (err) {
    // handle errors
});
```

Or Promise.all:

```
Promise.all([
    Visitor.count(dateRange).exec(),
    Account.count(dateRange).exec()
]).then(function(result){
    // result is an ordered array of all the promises result 
    json.newVisitors = result[0];
    json.newAccounts = result[1];
}).catch(function (err) {
    // handle errors
});
```

Comment: This is a good short way of doing it! You can also make things a bit more parallel...

Comment: In both cases, when I need to do `res.json(json)`, the problem is that the json is never going back to the client, so i am getting timeout after one minute~. its like the `.then()` function is not returning back to the client

Comment: @Shazam Add a `console.log(err);` inside the catch block, you may have a mongoose error.

Comment: Thanks!!! can you tell me please if I can avoid doing catch all the time and make from one place that catches all the errors and log it? thanks again! +1

Comment: You experienced it first hand, it's a best practice to catch any promise's errors. This link is very interesting: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html The Rookie mistake #3 shows a nice piece of code: `.catch(console.log.bind(console));`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
var path = require('path'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    router = express.Router(),
    Q = require('q');

router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {

  var json = {items:''};

  Q.fcall(function() {
        json.items += 'A';
      })
      .then(function() {
        json.items += 'B';
      })
      .then(function() {
        json.items += 'C';
      })
      .finally(function() {
        res.json(json);
      });
});

app.use('/', router);

var http = require('http');

var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('listening', function onListening() {
      var addr = server.address();
      var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
          ? 'pipe ' + addr
          : 'port ' + addr.port;
      console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
    }
);
```

Then

```
curl localhost:3000/dashboard
```

Returns:

```
{"items":"ABC"}
```

**P.S.** You might also want to investigate [`async-q`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-q) et. al.:

```
async.series([
  ->
    ### do some stuff ###
    Q 'one'
  ->
    ### do some more stuff ... ###
    Q 'two'
]).then (results) ->
    ### results is now equal to ['one', 'two'] ###
    doStuff()
  .done()

### an example using an object instead of an array ###
async.series({
  one: -> Q.delay(200).thenResolve(1)
  two: -> Q.delay(100).thenResolve(2)
}).then (results) ->
    ### results is now equal to: {one: 1, two: 2} ###
    doStuff()
  .done()
```

UPDATED (a bit forced, I would just use `async`):

```
var path = require('path'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    router = express.Router(),
    Q = require('q'),
    async = require('async-q');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));

router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {

  var json = {};

  async.series({
        newVisitors: function() {
          return Q.Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            console.log(arguments);
            Visitor.count(dateRange, function(err, data) {
              if(err) return reject(err);
              resolve(data);
            });
          });
        },
        newAccounts: function() {
          return Q.Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            Account.count(dateRange, function(err, data) {
              if(err) return reject(err);
              resolve(data);
            });
          });
        }
  })
      .then(function(json) {
        res.json(json);
      });
});

app.use('/', router);

var http = require('http');

var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('listening', function onListening() {
      var addr = server.address();
      var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
          ? 'pipe ' + addr
          : 'port ' + addr.port;
      console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
    }
);
```

Now returns:

```
{"newVisitors": 1,"newAccounts":2}
```

Comment: As odd as it sounds, finally get executed as the first one, instead of last one.